# Resize windows console to fullscreen in C

Tags: c++, c, winapi

Is it possible to resize the console in a windows console application to fullscreen size?

It is possible to do that in the preferences of the windows, after the console was opened, but  I cannot figure out how to do it programmatically.

Comment: Surely a console app, by it's very definition, does not know it's in a window and so can't do anything to its window as there's no API available to console programs to do this.

Comment: @Skizz - Actually there are quite a few API functions that apps can use to manipulate the console:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682073%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get a handle to the console window using [GetConsoleWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Once you have that, you should be able to resize it using [SetWindowPos](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633545%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

You may also need to resize the buffer for the console using [SetConsoleScreenBufferSize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686044%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) prior to resizing the window.

ETA:

Others have mentioned using SetConsoleDisplayMode to display the console in full-screen (non-windowed) mode.  I'm not sure if this is really what you wanted or not though.  I haven't seen any apps use non-windowed mode since the windows 98 days.

Comment: `SetWindowPos` isn't the right tool for this. I believe the right one is `SetConsoleMode`.

Comment: @chris - I'm not seeing anything in SetConsoleMode that would allow for resizing.  The console is a window just like any other, so I don't see how getting a handle to it and resizing it would be inappropriate.

Comment: When I click the Maximize button in a command window, it maximizes the height but not the width (in Windows 7). To do the same you would use `ShowWindow`.

Comment: My bad, it's `SetConsoleDisplayMode`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686028(v=vs.85).aspx Of course this is fullscreen. @Erik, are you trying to maximize it or make it fullscreen? These are two different things, and the first requires more than simply resizing the window.

Comment: My main concern is actually getting the width to increase above the default width when you click maximize.

Comment: @Erik, in that case, I see a `GetLargestConsoleWindowSize`, but not anything to set it. I believe it updates with the next console window opened once you change it in the registry, but I'm not sure if there's any better way of doing that. My guess is probably not, seeing as how it doesn't update the windows you have open.

Comment: I see ... I guess I just have to take it as is. It's only windows :)

Comment: `SetConsoleDisplayMode` is the right function, but not all hardware supports text-mode (i.e. fullscreen console) these days.